# I have some text [text1] [number2] [text3] in a line.I want to extract only the [text3] portion.My Code is working fine.But i cannot handle

Tags: java, string, apache

my file is here

```
private static final String FILENAME = "rea/data.txt";  //my file path

              try {
                     fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
                     br = new BufferedReader(fr);    
                     String sCurrentLine;
                     sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
                     String lastline="";
                     String firstLine=br.readLine();
                     if ( (firstLine.contains("[INFO]") && (firstLine.contains("[OHS_Batch_Restart_utils.sh]")) || (firstLine.contains("[DEBUG]")) && (firstLine.contains("[AppRestart.sh]")) || (firstLine.contains("[INFO]")) && (firstLine.contains("[AppRestart.sh]")) ))  // to check lines condition
                  {          
                     int firstpos= StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(firstLine, "[", 3);   // getting 3rd occurence of parentheses
                     int secondpos= StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(firstLine, "]", 3);   // getting 3rd occurence of parentheses
                     System.out.println(firstLine.substring(firstpos,secondpos+1)); //printing value between the 3rd occurence of parentheses                         
                  }while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null ){               
                       lastline=sCurrentLine; //fixing lst line as currentline
                  }                        
                 if ( (lastline.startsWith("[INFO]") && (lastline.contains("[OHS_Batch_Restart_utils.sh]")) || (lastline.startsWith("[DEBUG]")) && (lastline.contains("[AppRestart.sh]")) || (lastline.startsWith("[INFO]")) && (lastline.contains("[AppRestart.sh]")))) //same condition**strong text**
                 { 
                 int firstpos= StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(lastline, "[", 3);     // getting 3rd occurence of parentheses
                 int secondpos= StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(lastline, "]", 3);   // getting 3rd occurence of parentheses
                         System.out.println(lastline.substring(firstpos,secondpos+1));         

                 }
```

i cannot handle exception.If i dont have any 3rd occurence of [ ] parentheses i am getting stringindexoutofbound exception else i am getting null pointer exception

Comment: please help me handle exceptions.

Comment: Hi Sanmoy, there are a few issues with your question. First of all your code is not well formatted and does not compile. Second you didn't provide the input you're using - the content of your file. Third you did not provide the error message(s) or stack trace(s). Please revise your question to provide all of these things and it will be easier for others to help you. Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing that complex starts with etc as value inside [] can change. Why don't you try this?

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class FindThirdMatchInSquareBracketUtil{

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String s = "[text1] [number2] [text3]";
  String s2 = "[text1] [number2] ";
  System.out.println(getThirdMatch(s));
  System.out.println(getThirdMatch(s2));


 }

 private static String getThirdMatch(String s) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

  int counter = 1;

  while (m.find()) {
   if (counter == 3) {
    return m.group(1);
   }
   counter++;

  }
  return null;
 }
}
```